# Fail to deploy node.js application to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple node.js express-based application to heroku, something which is apparently very basic: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cours-lic3-blois",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
    "github-flavored-markdown": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.8",
    "npm": "1.1.65"
  }
}
```

When I `git push heroku master` I got the following trace:

```
 -----> Heroku receiving push
 -----> Node.js app detected
 -----> Resolving engine versions
        Using Node.js version: 0.8.8
        Using npm version: 1.1.65
 -----> Fetching Node.js binaries
 -----> Vendoring node into slug
 -----> Installing dependencies with npm
        npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_1suuxlhd9s8n6/node_modules/express/bin/express'
        npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
        npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
        npm ERR! or email it to:
        npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

        npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-348-ec2
        npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-tonf/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-NG88/cli.js" "rebuild"
        npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1suuxlhd9s8n6
        npm ERR! node -v v0.8.8
        npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.65
        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_1suuxlhd9s8n6/node_modules/express/bin/express
        npm ERR! code ENOENT
        npm ERR! errno 34
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_1suuxlhd9s8n6/npm-debug.log
        npm ERR! not ok code 0
  !     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm
  !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

 To git@heroku.com:fast-everglades-2007.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fast-everglades-2007.git'
```

I tried to tweak various versions in my package.json but to no avail. I am developing on windows and it might be possible this ENOENT issue is due to some filemode issue.

Comment: Try again. The npm repository throws these errors sometimes even when you run from a local environment

Comment: I tried several times in a row that's why I asked the question. Will retry...

Answer (score 18):

I got this fixed by:

- Making sure Procfile is committed into git
- Removing the node_modules/ folder and committing that into git (git rm -r node_modules/)

Afterwards, I did the git push heroku master then the error disappeared.

Comment: This fixed it for me, and adding node_modules/ to .gitignore

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to run "npm install -g express-generator" and run "express ." in order to create a package.json file

Comment: After 3 hours, I saw this and its fixed now. Thanks a ton, man.

Comment: can anyone provid the exact command to fix this problem, how to install npm node_modules into git ?

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem, and it was because:

1. I keep `node_modules` in version control
2. I had `bin` in my .gitignore file

`npm` was attempting to `chmod express/bin/express`, but due to my `.gitignore` this file wasn't in git and thus was not being cloned during the deploy, so it failed. I didn't notice it because a local `npm` install would create the `bin/express` file as usual.

Removing `bin` from `.gitignore` and committing the missing files solved the problem for me.

Comment: For me it was that I had *node_modules* in .gitignore.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku team, could you please consider configuring npm to use `npm install --no-bin-links --production` by default, or creating an environment variable to let users set that flag. This is a serious bug in node installs. Removing the bin directory from my .gitignore (as suggested below) enabled me to deploy, but it breaks using git effectively in a cross-platform development environment, requiring an explicit npm rebuild on every git pull where node_modules might have changed.

NPM best practice is to avoid having node_modules in .gitignore (see http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html ).

I believe `--no-bin-links` will provide the best of both worlds, enabling deploys of node_modules where the bin directory has been excluded, supporting npm rebuild, but not failing when a bin link is created.

I submitted a pull request here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/33

Thanks!

Comment: Is --no-bin-links really helps? I am experimenting with checking in node_modules into git (excluding the bin folders) and I am running into the same issue even locally (eventually want to deploy to beanstalk)

Answer (score 0):

similar issue was fixed by renaming gruntfile.js to Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago, I think it was because I imported a module created by me and that was what gave the error;
I corrected it like this:
I called the module "path"
`const path = require ("path")`
and then where my module was imported I made a join of the file path
`const myModule = require (path.join (__ dirname, 'MyModule.js'))`