# libxmljs: scons command not found

Tags: node.js, makefile, scons, libxml-js

When I was trying to deploy my node.js app (with both nodejitsu and heroku), I got the same errors with libxmljs.

```
> libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/libxmljs
> make node

make: scons: Command not found
make: *** [node] Error 127
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-stringify
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-parse
npm http 200 https://registry.nodejitsu.com/is-promise/-/is-promise-1.0.1.tgz

> libxmljs@0.4.1 preuninstall /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/libxmljs
> make clean

make: scons: Command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
npm http GET https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-stringify/-/css-stringify-1.0.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.nodejitsu.com/css-parse/-/css-parse-1.0.4.tgz
npm WARN continuing anyway libxmljs@0.4.1 preuninstall: `make clean`
npm WARN continuing anyway Exit status 2
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall: `make node`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.4.1 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make node
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System SunOS 5.11
npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/local/bin/npm" "install" "--loglevel=http"
npm ERR! cwd /root/tmp/tmp-31613c7bs0y8/build/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

As you can see, it is failing within libxmljs's 'make node' and 'make clean' as the command 'scons' is not found. I have libxmljs installed in my app's node_modules directory, and 'scons' is located at "/usr/local/bin/scons".

I believe I have to ensure that the location of scons is in the path for the make environment of libxmljs but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: Following the advice from this question ([Fail to deploy node.js application to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321231/fail-to-deploy-node-js-application-to-heroku)) I added libxmljs to the dependencies in package.json and added node_modules/ to .gitignore, that way heroku could have a look at the dependencies and install them itself. However, the exact same error occurred, which leads me to believe the root of the problem is not with my local environment, but something larger regarding libxmljs?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem, although it wasn't really specifically about libxmljs. I also used the 'twilio' node submodule in my app, but listed its version as '0.0.0' in dependencies. I guess twilio 0.0.0 used libxmljs which wouldn't install when deploying to heroku, so I updated the twilio version number to the actual current version, and everything's good to go!